# JMeter unrecognized command -genkeypair

Tags: java, jmeter, keytool, recorder, key-pair

If I try to start recording with JMeter I get the error `unrecognized command -genkeypair`.

This error is shown because there exists 2 versions of the tool `keytool`.

- The 'system' keytool: [Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/keytool.j2se14.1.html)
- Orcacle's java keytool: [Manuals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

JMeter is using the wrong, system keytool and this doesn't know the option '-genkeypair'.

How to force Apache JMeter to use the keytool of java JDK/JRE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try was to set the JAVA Path in $PATH with `PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin` but this was not the solution, because JMeter nevertheless uses the first found/discovered keytool-path in $PATH.

And this was the solution: I set the path to the java keytool not at the end of $PATH but on the beginning.

`PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Hope it helps you too.